# drag and drop table columns in angular which has input and checkbox fields

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to drag and drop my table columns which also consists of input and checkbox fields.When i am trying,i am able to drag and drop only static coulmns but not input and checkbox.Please help

cdk-table

Comment: create stackblitz example of what you have already done

Answer (score 0):

You need to change string arrays of Drag & drop with components arrays.
Here is an example how to load dynamicly components inside main component: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Actualy this could be more helpfull: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components/

Comment: Thanks.I tried that.I am able to drag and drop columns but its not working with images.